# Major problem creating more problems, spiraling out of control endlessly: cannot install OS

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, install, ssd

I started the day by receiving the following message, spontaneously:

> your computer restarted because of a problem. Press a key or wait a few minutes to continue starting up.

So I upgraded High Sierra. But the problem continued, I kept getting the message above.

So I uninstalled all my apps which came from outside the Apple store.  Throughout this process, the problem continued.

Finally, I thought I might as well just reinstall everything. After all, everything I have is in one cloud or another anyway. I started the computer in recovery mode and just wiped the main drive. Easy! *And very possibly stupid.*

When I went to install High Sierra again, I got the error, though I tried twice in a row.

> could not create reboot volume ...

Yikes. So I started her up again, CMD R, and a little globe starts spinning. Eventually, I am given the option to install OS X Yosemite. Ok, fine, better than nothing.... but then when it says select the disk you want, there are no options... just the external USB drive...

When I go to disk utility, I see “500.28 GB APPLE SSD...” with a little grey “disk0s2” beneath it.

[image]

What should I do now? I feel WAAAY over my head here...

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the equivalent of feeling a pain in your chest and immediately going straight for the heart transplant.  I am hoping that somewhere in this you backed up you data.  Now, the first question is, what type (model) of Mac do you have?  Secondly, when you boot from Install/Recovery, go into Terminal and type the following `diskutil list` and post the output.

Comment: Yes, it’s a hell of a Monday already! I have a MacBook Pro. But, I can’t easily post the output. One sec while I find a solution, maybe take a pho

Comment: Ok I pasted a photo... already relieved that you seem so cool-headed

Comment: Ok, uploading it now...

Comment: Yes, I think around 2012, I’m not exactly sure. Excuses!

Comment: I think a total wipe is the best option, but when I do as you suggest, I see “there does appear to be enough arguments for the number of partitions you specified”

Comment: I can’t stress enough how much I appreciate your advice...

Comment: No worries! Understandable that you have other priorities than a complete stranger’s computer failure ...

Comment: Hey looks like it worked ... hallelujah !!! I now see “MacOS extended (journaled). Use disk utility to enable journaling or reformat the disk”

Comment: Oh not so fast... after enable journaling “the additional components needed to install OS X can’t be found”

Comment: Oh just tried it again and something is happening ... let’s see what the situation is in **squints** 4 hours and 24 minutes !! Anyway, you’re the best Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Having a bunch of kernel panics is not normal. While it can be a software problem, it often is a hardware problem.

First, run Apple Diagnostics or Apple Hardware Test. If no errors are reported, start from Internet Recovery, create a new partition on your SSD, and reinstall the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is to destroy and recreate a clean partition then perform a full re-installation

1. Issue the command

   `diskutil partitionDisk disk0 1 GPT HFS+ MacHD 100%`

   This command will create a single GPT partition formatted for HFS+ with a name of MacHD.  You can change the name if you like, but use quotes if you use a name with spaces like "Macintosh HD".
2. Install your macOS as normal.  You can enable Journaling and/or FileValut at this point.