# My Fusion Drive Partitioning Seems Wrong/Strange/Wonky

Tags: hard-drive, partition, core-storage

See below for `diskutil list` of my 3TB fusion drive (iMac 27" late 2014) running High Sierra: I assume `disk0` is the HD and `disk1` is the SSD, and `disk2` is the virtual combo that is mounted as my "HD". But I've got a 2 questions:

1. Why does `disk0` have two `Apple_CoreStorage` partitions? I'd like to do a clean install of Mojave for my upgrade, and if the partitioning is wrong, how do I fix? I assume erasing the disk as part of the upgrade won't change the partitioning. And partitions 2 and 4 are not adjacent, so not clear how I'd merge. And Disk Utility just shows a single 3.1TB drive. Or should I not care?
2. When I mount and look at the EFI partitions on Disk0 and Disk1, I just see an Apple sub-directory... no Windows/Microsoft anything. And the Startup Disk Utility also only shows "Macintosh HD / MacOS 10.3.6" as an option. But when I boot up holding down <kbd>Option</kbd> key, I see a Windows boot option. Where is this boot option hiding?

```
    **/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER**
       0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *3.0 TB     disk0
       1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
       2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            2.2 TB     disk0s2
       3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.1 MB   disk0s3
       4:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            801.4 GB   disk0s4
       5:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s5
    
    **/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER**
       0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk1
       1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
       2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            121.0 GB   disk1s2
       3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk1s3
    
    **/dev/disk2 (internal, virtual):
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER**
       0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +3.1 TB     disk2
            Logical Volume on disk1s2, disk0s2, ...
            F8575B66-EA8C-4260-96E8-7FEFD183EFC3
            Unencrypted Fusion Drive
```

```
CoreStorage Logical Volume Groups
|
+-- Logical Vol Group 8AAC.. 
 ===== 
 Name: Macintosh HD 
 Size: 3.1 TB 
 | 
 +- Phys Vol 1ADA.. 
 |   Index: 0 
 |   Disk: disk1s2 
 |   Size: 121.0 GB 
 +- Phys Vol 37D1.. 
 |   Index: 1 
 |   Disk: disk0s2 
 |   Size: 2.2 TB 
 +- Phys Vol CFB5... 
 |   Index: 2 
 |   Disk: disk0s4 
 |   Size: 801.4 GB 
 +- Logical Vol Family A061..
 ---
   | 
   | +- Logical Vol F857.. 
   | Disk: disk2 
   | Size (Tot): 3.1 TB 
   | Revertible: No 
   | LV Name: Macintosh HD 
   | Volume Name: Macintosh HD 
   | Content Hint: Apple_HFS LVG 
   | Type: Fusion, Sparse
```

Comment: There's a lot to unpack here....   Starting with the partitioning of a drive for a clean install.....  If you're doing a complete wipe of the system and want to destroy all the partions, you can use the command found in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/314750/119271).  Just do that to all your disks to ensure they're blank.  (Make sure you have a *working* method to reinstall macOS

Comment: Next, it seems you have some (possibly) previously created core storage volumes.  Issue the command `diskutil coreStorage list` and post that output as well.  Finally, when you boot into Windows, do you get a full Windows environment?

Comment: Please add that to the the original post by editing the question.  It’s next to impossible to read that especially on a mobile device

Comment: So if I boot from USB, make sure disk0 has no mounted partitions, and use the command 'diskutil partitionDisk disk0 1 GPT HFS+ MacHD 100%' it seems I'd get a "clean disk". But that spawns two new questions: 1) Seems like I'd lose my "Apple_Boot Recovery HD" and "Apple_Boot OS X" partitions (not sure why I have two Apple_Boot partitions), and 2) Will the virtual Fusion Drive (disk2) which is a logical addition of coreStorage partitions on disk0 and disk1 "figure out" what I'm doing, reconfigure itself appropriately, and continue to function properly?

Comment: As to your questions:  1) Your recovery partition will be recreated with the fresh install of macOS  2)  No.  It won't "figure out" anything and it won't function.  If you're doing a complete wipe as you alluded to in the original question, then you want to wipe all of your disks clean and start with a clean slate.

Comment: Looking at your CoreStorage volume, it appears you have a single drive made up of three partitions - the 128GB SSD and 2 partitions on the HDD.  I've not seen this config before - is this how you got it from Apple?

Comment: @Allen all the info/help is very much appreciated. I had set up a Windows partition (bootcamp or parallels, can't remember which) way back when I initially set up the iMac, so likely the 2nd partition was created during that setup event. I "reclaimed" that partition's space via Disk Utility in the somewhat recent past.

Comment: So I *think* the steps for a clean upgrade (and filesystem repair) from High Sierra to Mojave are: 1) boot from USB, 2) re-partition the disk with 'diskutil partitionDisk disk0 1 GPT HFS+ MacHD 100%', 3) run 'diskutil resetFusion', 4) install Mojave. That sound about right?

Comment: If it was parallels, then it's a VM within macOS - you won't see it.  If you reclaimed the space...well, it's gone.

Comment: Do you want a fresh clean installation on your Fusion drive with no remnants of what was there previously?  I'm assuming you have a bootable USB and backups of all your data.

Comment: Yes, clean install & fix the filesystem. I have a bootable USB w/ Mojave and my data is backed up.

Answer (score 2):

This procedure is going to get you back to a "factory fresh" system where your 128GB SSD and 3TB (spinning) HDD are configured as a Fusion Drive.  Basically, we're going to:

- Delete all partitions off all the physical drives
- Create the Fusion Drive
- Install macOS

Before you begin, ensure that you have

- all necessary backups.
- a bootable USB installer
- WiFi and a working Internet connection (if you want to use Internet Recovery)

#### Erase the Disks

Using a bootable USB macOS installer, boot up then go into Terminal and issue the following commands:

```
$ diskutil partitionDisk disk0 1 GPT HFS+ MacSSD 100%

$ diskutil partitionDisk disk1 1 GPT HFS+ MacHDD 100%
```

Verify that the disks are wiped clean by issuing the command

```
$ diskutil list
```

You should see two disks with a single partition each.

#### Create the Fusion Drive

**Create the Logical Volume Group**

Next create a logical volume group by "combining" the two drives with the following command

```
$ diskutil coreStorage create <LogicalVolumeGroupName> /dev/disk1 /dev/disk2
```

You can use any descriptive name for the group.  Ex:  `iMacLVG`

When the process has finished, it will output some status information including the logical volume group UUID like below:

```
Core Storage LVG UUID: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Copy that number to your clipboard.  You will need it for the next command.

**Create the Logical Volume**

Issue the command

```
$ diskutil coreStorage createVolume lvgUUID type name size
```

Where...

- `lvgUUID` = the UUID you copied from the last step
- `type` = the format you want to you.
- `name` = the name of the Volume.
- `size` = how big you want to make the volume.  Valid entries are in bytes (Kilo, Mega, Giga, Tera, Peta, etc.) and percentage (%)

So, to make a volume that spans the whole logical volume in HFS+ use the following example:

```
 $ diskutil coreStorage createVolume  XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX HFS+ "iMac HD" 100%
```

Once it's done, you've got a clean volume on which to install macOS.  Issue the command to verify that you've got 3 disks:  2 physical and 1 logical.

#### Install macOS

Exit Terminal and complete the macOS installation.  Restore your data by using the Data Migration Tool if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for laying this all out so clearly. It appears that the Mojave version of 'diskutil' now has a 'resetFusion' option, which claims to do *all* of the steps for you (repartition with GPT maps, create Core Storage Fusion Drive volume, etc.). I think the above steps are for pre-Mojave 'diskutil'. Thoughts on using the resetFusion option instead?

Comment: I haven't gone to Mojave yet because I'm always leery of new OS releases (all vendors).  I have it on a machine I "play" with, but nothing I do actual work on.  I haven't tried out the "resetFusion" function, but since you're willing to wipe the drives anyway - I say give it a go. If it doesn't work, then you have these instructions to fall back on.  To put it another way...you won't break anything!

Comment: A final thanks to @Allen here since, as I'm new to the platform, I'm not yet allowed to upvote his answer. After an extra set of backups to Dropbox and to a spare external drive, I'll give it a try. If the upgrade process is successful, I'll add a final comment so that folks know the "resetFusion" option works.

Comment: To my way of thinking `diskutil coreStorage create <LogicalVolumeGroupName> /dev/disk1 /dev/disk2` should be `diskutil coreStorage create <LogicalVolumeGroupName> /dev/disk0 /dev/disk1`. Although I have not tested this.