# New SSD Fitted but Disk Utility Still Showing Old Disk

Tags: macos, hard-drive, time-machine, disk-utility, mac-mini

My 2013 Mac Mini with 1 TB Fusion drive was starting to run really slowly.  I got a brand new 1 TB SSD fitted and am trying to restore from Time Machine, now.  The restore can see the Time Machine drive no problem, but when it goes forward to choose a destination disk, there is no disk indicated.

So I restart the restore process, and this time go into disk utility.  What's strange is that I can see the Samsung SSD, but also the original Macintosh HD.  I know that it's not there, as I have it sitting next to me (and besides.. can Minis have more than one internal drive?).

So I guess what I need to do is to remove the "ghost" disk from Disk Utility and then prepare the SSD as "Macintosh HD" to accept my restore.

Can someone tell me how I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are experiencing is because you only replaced the 1TB *spinning* portion of the Fusion drive; the 128GB SSD is still there with the boot partition on it.

You've confirmed this when you said that you can see both the Samsung SSD *and* the original HD.  What you need to do now is wipe both and create a new Fusion drive to combine the 128GB SSD and the 1TB SSD into one CoreStorage volume.

I've detailed these steps in [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/353035/119271) on how to do this.  Since you've got everything backed up with Time Machine and are using it for recovery, you should have no problems migrating your data over.

Comment: Thanks, Allan.  How do I create the bootable disk mentioned in your link?  Or is that the Time Machine drive?

Comment: That’s the bootable USB installer.  Unfortunately, you’re past that point unless you have another Mac.  For now, just use Internet recovery as you’ve been doing

Comment: I have another Mac, and have just created the installer.   I'll now go and use your method, thanks. :-)

Comment: OK so I have got as far as `diskutil coreStorage createVolume XXXXetc. HFS+ "iMac HD" 100%` 

The output is 'the given file system is not supported on Core Storage (-69756)'

Comment: Try it with just HFS instead.  You can wipe it later.

Comment: So another issue.  I installed MacOS, and then I ran 'Restore from a Time Machine backup', and that seemed to work.  But even when I remove the Time Machine volume from the Mac and restart, it still comes up on 'OSX Utilities'.

Comment: You should have used a Migration assistant.  Restoring like that overwrites everything you just did

Comment: But I want to restore the Mac to the position it was in just before I unplugged it to have the disk fitted.